# hibernate validator doen't work with Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I'm following an example project from Spring in action 4th book. However, I was blocked at Chapter5, where using hibernate validator to validate values submit by a form. Here are some related codes:

I hava a model named Spitter:

```
package spittr;


import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;


public class Spitter {

    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5, max=16)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5, max=25)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    public Spitter() {
    }

    public Spitter(String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this(null, username, password, firstName, lastName, email);
    }

    public Spitter(Long id, String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, that, "firstName", "lastName", "username", "password", "email");
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this, "firstName", "lastName", "username", "password", "email");
    }

}
```

Controller collect form data and validate them:

```
package spittr.web;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import spittr.Spitter;
import spittr.data.SpitterRepository;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spitter")
public class SpitterController {

    private SpitterRepository spitterRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SpitterController(SpitterRepository spitterRepository) {
        this.spitterRepository = spitterRepository;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processRegistration(@Valid Spitter spitter, Errors errors) {
        System.out.println(errors.hasErrors() + ": has errors...");
        if (errors.hasErrors()){
            return "registerForm";
        }
        spitterRepository.save(spitter);
        return "redirect:/spitter/" + spitter.getUsername();
    }
}
```

And the config files(Java based):

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"spittr"},
        excludeFilters = {
                @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = EnableWebMvc.class)
        })
public class RootConfig {
}
```

SpitterWebInitializer:
    package spittr.config;

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import spittr.web.WebConfig;

public class SpitterWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

WebConfig
    package spittr.web;

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("spittr.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
//apply from: 'gretty.plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.7.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.7.RELEASE"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.3.2.Final"
    //providedCompile "org.glassfish.web:javax.el:2.2.4"
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api
    providedCompile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '1.1.0.Final'

    compile "javax.servlet:jstl:1.2"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1"
    def tomcatVersion = '7.0.59'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
    providedCompile "javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.1"
    providedCompile "javax.el:javax.el-api:2.2.4"
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    maven{ url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'}
    maven { url 'http://maven.springframework.org/release' }
    maven { url 'http://maven.springframework.org/milestone' }
    maven { url 'http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'http://download.java.net/maven/2' }
    mavenCentral()

}

war {
    baseName = 'spittr'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

tomcat {
    httpPort = 8080
    httpsPort = 8443
    enableSSL = true
//    contextPath = 'sample-app'
}
```

Full porject available at GitHub: https://github.com/zmrenwu/Spittr

I spend several days on Google and Stackoverflow for searching sulutions, but no luck.

Please give me some help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Gradle but I think it will work if you **delete** this line :

```
providedCompile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '1.1.0.Final'
```

At least I tested it with Maven and it solved the problem.

Comment: This would cause a new problem seems related to gradle tomcat plugin which I also have no idea about it.

Comment: This solution worked with Gradle too, I justed tested it : I have cloned your Github repo. Then I have replaced the content of the `build.gradle` by the one you have posted on Stackoverflow. Then I have added a bunch of `@NotNull` and `@Size` annotations and, as you describe in your post, the validation did not work. But then I commented out this line and the validation worked fine. Note: I ran the application with the command `gradle tomcatRun`.

Comment: So strange, what gradle version have you used?

Comment: I used the bundled gradle wrapper of your Github repo -- which is gradle 4.10 apparently.

Comment: If i comment out this line, then run gradle tomcatRun, I got such exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation....

Comment: I tried various things to reproduce this new problem, but without success. Sorry. I'll let you know if I have an idea... Maybe you can try to run `gradlew tomcatRun` if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks! Still not working. May it related to IDEA, I use IDEA as development tool

Comment: I tried Eclipse and the command line and I just tried IntelliJ IDEA, it worked each time. I'm on Windows, maybe that's the difference...

Comment: What JDK version you are using? I use JDK10, it's that not compatible? If you use a lower version, I will try to you version.

Comment: I use JDK 8, I haven't try with JDK 10.

Comment: I also trie on JDK 8, same problem.

Comment: Add I tried on win10 too，different exception raised: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcUriComponentsContributor' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed;

Comment: I cannot test right now, so I'm not sure but I think I had this error when `hibernate-validator` was `6.0.13.Final`. It was solved by downgrading to `5.3.2.Final`.

Comment: Downgrading to 5.3.2.Final solved the problem. It's so kind of you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Finally we made it! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Validated` annotation to your controller class:

```
@Controller
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/spitter")
public class SpitterController {

...
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

hibernate-validator is by default is using javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final

[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:

Try to upgrade to latest version javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final  this worked for me.

Comment: I upgrade: compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.0.13.Final", providedCompile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final', still not working.